replace part of string in json in a fetch-response
I'm trying to replace part of a response before outputting it to a html document. Specifically I want to delete part of the response using replace.
fetch('https://api.foo.bar/5H2F8QXNTRW7P7LNL1KHXL76JQXXI2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json.replace(" and null Cent", "")) // trying to delete this part
    .then(json => document.getElementById("betrag").innerHTML = json)
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));

It's been working fine until I tried to delete part of the response. The console shows
Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

I'm not getting this error without the line trying to replace part of the response. I#m lost.
I tried json.replace and response.replace without success.

You need to pass a function, not the return value of the function: .then(json => json.replace(" and null Cent", ""))

Calling replace on an object probably doesn't make much sense here. Unless the JSON response would happen to be nothing but a plain string, you either need to do this before you decode the response as JSON, or access a specific value inside the object and replace in that value only.

fetch('https://api.foo.bar/5H2F8QXNTRW7P7LNL1KHXL76JQXXI2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        // Convert the JSON object to a string to perform the replacement
        let jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);

        // Replace the specific part of the text
        jsonString = jsonString.replace(" and null Cent", "");

        // Parse the modified string back to a JSON object
        let modifiedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        // Update the HTML element with the modified JSON data
        document.getElementById("betrag").innerHTML = modifiedJson;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));


Not sure why this was downvoted, perhaps add an explanation (beyond the comments)?   Note: .then(json => { is confusing as, at that point, it's not json (a string) but an object.   response.json() = "parse JSON response into native JavaScript objects", not return the json string.   So jsonString is redundant as json, by definition, is a string.

Why parse the JSON into object, then call JSON.stringify() to turn it back to JSON?

Change .then(response => response.json()) to .then(response => response.text()) and remove the JSON.stringify

The issue here is that you're trying to use the replace method on the json object, but json is not defined in that scope. The replace method is a string method, so you need to use it on a string.
Assuming the API returns a JSON object with a string property that you want to modify, you can do something like this:
fetch('https://api.foo.bar/5H2F8QXNTRW7P7LNL1KHXL76JQXXI2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        // Assuming json is an object with a string property
        // Replace the string property with the modified string
        for (const key in json) {
            if (typeof json[key] === 'string') {
                json[key] = json[key].replace(" and null Cent", "");
            }
        }
        return json;
    })
    .then(json => document.getElementById("betrag").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json))
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));

If the API returns a plain string, you can simply use the replace method on the response text:
fetch('https://api.foo.bar/5H2F8QXNTRW7P7LNL1KHXL76JQXXI2')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => text.replace(" and null Cent", ""))
    .then(text => document.getElementById("betrag").innerHTML = text)
    .catch(err => console.log('Request Failed', err));

Note that in the first example, I used JSON.stringify(json) to convert the JSON object to a string before assigning it to the innerHTML property. This is because innerHTML expects a string, not a JSON object.

Quick reminder that AI generated content is banned. Also, the first approach won't work if the JSON had more than 1 layer.

I might put in an error, since it din't work for me. @crazy-volt's answer worked though, so I'm rolling with it.
